# Way to automate LOADS of nested for-loops? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D integer array of length [9][3][3]. Every element in the array is initialised at a value of 1.

I want the very last element of the array (i.e. [8][2][2]) to cycle through all values 1 through 9. Then I want that same element to cycle through them again, for every time the element before it (i.e. [8][2][1]) increases by 1 up until 9. Likewise THIS element cycles through all values 1-9 for every increase of the previous element [8][2][0]. The only thing I can think if is manually setting up 81 nested for-loops, but this would take forever and is incredibly inefficient. I'm sure there's a better way.

Sorry if I'm not very good at explaining myself. Basically let's suppose this 3D array were output entirely in one line. At first it would look something like this:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Then I want that last digit on the right to repeatedly cycle through 1-9, and every time that happens, the one immediately to the left of it increases by 1. Then when THAT one reaches 9, the one to the left of it increases by 1. And so on. Repeat for all 81 elements of the array.

What's a better way to do this rather than 81 nested for-loops?

I apologise for any inaccuracy of terminology or lack of clarity. I'm self taught and rubbish at explaining myself.

Comment: `"I want the very last element of the array (i.e. [8][2][2]) to cycle through all values 1 through 9."` -- the very last element is but a single int, not an array of ints. Do you wish it to change over time? I'm not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to make a very large counter?

Comment: I'm unclear of the purpose of this. It would just result in an array full of 9's. And why is it stored as an array? If you simply created a `BigInteger` with 81 1's, then added the value of `1` to it until the number was 81 9's you would get the same result with less overhead.

Comment: Writing 81 nested loop is worse than writing 1000 ifs. No, you will never ever need to do that. There will be some other ways. However, I am not sure what you exactly want. How can [8][2][2] be the last array element?

Comment: Good luck waiting or that program to terminate. `9^81` is a rather large number. Your program will take forever (at least it won't terminate while you're still alive, I guess).

Comment: @Dando18, yes, worst case scenario it will end in an array full of 9s. I'm actually working on a brute force algorithm and for every change in one of the values it will check to see if it's right.

Comment: First of all, whether a 3D int array is the suitable data structure for your program is something if you can think about. Perhaps a tree or linked list might be a better choice.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is a good way of putting what I'm trying to do, yes. Basically generating every single possible outcome of 81 values that can take the values 1-9.

Comment: @user3437460 I've not provided the exact context/purpose of the code as this is a generic question, but it does need to be in a 3D array, yes.

I say that [8][2][2] is the last element assuming [0][0][0] is the first.

Comment: @ampharos Am I right to say what you wanted is to generate all combinations of 81 digits values starting from 111....111 then 111...1112  till 999...999?

Comment: @user3437460 Exactly so! I'm aware it'll take aeons for it to compute, but actually running it isn't my purpose here. It's just a thought process I'm trying to write down in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is like a complex version of incrementing an 81-digit base-9 number, but here it is. As mentioned in comments, you might go on with your life while waiting for it to complete.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][][] data = new int[9][3][3];
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                data[x][y][z] = 1;
    print(data);

    OUTER: while (true) {
        int x = 8, y = 2, z = 2;
        while (true) {
            if (data[x][y][z] < 9) {
                data[x][y][z]++;
                break;
            }
            data[x][y][z] = 1;
            if (--z < 0) {
                z = 2;
                if (--y < 0) {
                    y = 2;
                    if (--x < 0)
                        break OUTER;
                }
            }
        }
        print(data);
    }
}
private static void print(int[][][] data) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                System.out.print(data[x][y][z]);
    System.out.println();
}
```